# Difference between postgis.net and postgis.org for PostGIS documentation?

Tags: postgis, documentation

What is the difference between two sites hosting different PostGIS docs?

For example:

- http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html
- http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html

Comment: Links to refractions.net now return 404 Not Found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend never using postgis.org.

- **[PostGIS.net](http://postgis.net)** is the official domain of PostGIS. [PostGIS.net has the docs for all versions of PostGIS](http://postgis.net/documentation/).
- **PostGIS.org** is a domain owned by a private consultancy ["Refractions Research Inc"](http://refractions.net/) that hosts the old docs. They now redirect "documentation" to postgis.net, but they still host the old docs and rank high on Google.

As a side note, as of now, [postgis.org is hosting the docs for SVN 10789](http://postgis.org/docs/index.html) this is version 2.0.2. Postgis.net conversely [pegs the docs for `manual-2.0` at SVN 15183](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/).

Comment: As to *why* Refractions does this... the "support" tab on postgis.org provides information on Refractions' (paid) services.